# I'm having a problem when trying to diagonalize a matrix (with a parameter), how can I solve?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, diagonalization

I have this matrix, and I need to say where the matrix could be diagonalized. Alpha is a real parameter.

$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & \alpha  \\
3 & 1  \\
\end{matrix}
$$
I found characteristic polynomial, $ det(a) = (t*I - A) $

here's the final result:
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & -\alpha  \\
-3 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
and by computing the determinant of this 2-by-2 matrix I got: $0*0 - (-3*(-\alpha)$, which is equal to -3*(\alpha).
alpha is equal to zero, and its algebraic multiplicity is equal to 1, same for its geometric multiplicity.

I think there's an error here, because it's strange that the characteristic polynomial has this solution, because it's not possible to go forward, since according to spectral theorem a squared matrix could be diagonalized if and only if the sum of geometric multiplicities is equal to the order of the matrix. And it's not my case, because I have only 1 eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity equal to 1, so the geometric multiplicity must be 1 as well.

Comment: $tI-A$ has $t-1$ along the diagonal. The characteristic polynomial is $t^2-2t+(1-3\alpha)$. (Note that the characteristic polynomial is always monic.)

Comment: ahh you're right, when computing the characteristic polynomial I've forgot "t", and I've put 1 instead.

Comment: Happens to us all